# How to Launch multiple QUEUES same time to achieve multi threading in LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel, multithreading, multiprocessing, lumen

I want to fetch the data from the server at the same time by using multithreading.

The reason behind multi-threading is to avoid load on the server and its resources.

So, I found laravel queues and since I am new in laravel I don't know much about it but after r&d I did the work and develop a job that dispatches queues one after another BUT I want that queue will start at the same time

Comment: multi-threading does not avoid load on the server. if you separate it into multiple queues, instead of 1, more resources will be used in theory because each queue has it's own resources required just to run the queue, let alone the jobs that the queue processes. the answer is probably more likely in how you're handling the code that you want to put in the queue. but there's not enough info here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use Supervisor, Then you can config it by `numprocs=8` property to run e.g. 8 queue processes.

Here is the Laravel documentation about installing and configuring Supervisor: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#supervisor-configuration

You can also categorize your queues and dispatch your job to a particular queue ([here is the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#customizing-the-queue-and-connection)) then use Supervisor with a config file for each queue.

1. **Installing Supervisor**

> Supervisor is a process monitor for the Linux operating system, and
>   will automatically restart your `queue:work` process if it fails. To
>   install Supervisor on Ubuntu, you may use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

2. **Configuring Supervisor**

> Supervisor configuration files are typically stored in the
>   `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` directory. Within this directory, you may
>   create any number of configuration files that instruct supervisor how
>   your processes should be monitored. For example, let's create a
>   `laravel-worker.conf` file that starts and monitors a `queue:work`
>   process:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

> In this example, the `numprocs` directive will instruct Supervisor to run 8 `queue:work` processes and monitor all of them, automatically
>   restarting them if they fail. You should change the `queue:work sqs`
>   portion of the `command` directive to reflect your desired queue
>   connection.

Comment: what should be the right process to do it in localhost first?